# QField - Can't locate project folder

Tags: qgis, qfield

I've recently been doing a couple of eagle surveys using QField where I plot flight paths and such. The thing is, I can find and open the project from "Recent Projects" when starting QField, but when I try to locate the actual folder on my phone (to be able to export it to my PC), I can't find it.

Is there a way to locate the open project in QField, like it is on QGIS Desktop (properties/path)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is stored in a location only visible from a PC using a cable connection.
Connect to your phone (I assume it is android) by cable and look here: Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files'

It might be in a child folder from there, e.g. '...\Imported Projects'.

Also, see this article: https://www.opengis.ch/2022/03/05/qfield-users-sit-down-we-need-to-talk-about-storage-access-on-android%ef%bf%bc/